# How can I convert imageNamed to imageWithContentsOfFile?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I tried to convert `imageNamed:` to `imageWithContentsOfFile:` and I failed everytime. I could not see pictures on cells.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[cellCountry objectForKey:@"Country_Flag"]];
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

`[cellCountry objectForKey:@"Country_Flag"]` holds **flag1@2x.png**

Path of image files is **/Resources/Images**

and This is my attempt.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[cellCountry objectForKey:@"Country_Flag"] ofType:@"png"]];
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

How can I convert it? I am waiting your help...

Comment: Post your attempt to use `imageWithContentsOfFile:`.

Comment: I forgot to add my attempt. Sorry for that. I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt to use `imageWithContentsOfFile` is close. Since the value from `[cellCountry objectForKey:@"Country_Flag"]` already has the file extension, you can't also specify the extension when getting its path.

Try:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[cellCountry objectForKey:@"Country_Flag"] ofType:nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try out the following

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[
    [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mainScreenBackground" ofType:@"png"]]
```

Comment: Your `NSData` example has a serious problem.

Comment: And it's best to adapt your examples to fit what the OP has in their question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem with second example a little, i'll delete it by the way!

Comment: Your `NSData` example doesn't come close to being valid code.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh, don't be so... Harsh.. (sorry, I just had to. No disrespect to any of you) :-)

Comment: @MariusFalkenbergWaldal Actually, I was typing that and just about to submit it when I noticed the guy's username. I meant to cancel but somehow submitted it anyway. :)

Comment: I have edited the post and will get back to both of you with some research! :) Sorry for any inconvenience caused!